# Can I turn the light of my ebike permanently on in the shimano etube project settings?

Tags: shimano, led-lights, steps

The little button on my headunit SC-E6010 broke while light was switched off. Now lights are off. I know that once they are on, and you turn the bike off and back on, light will be on again. So if I could switch the lights on from a connected computer, I wouldn't need the switch on the headunit anymore. Anyone know this or can verify that this strategy would work?

Answer (score 3):

There are two "e-tube projects" apps, a consumer one and a professional one.

The consumer one only connects through Bluetooth (from a phone), requires a compatible bike computer (that has Bluetooth), but is limited to basic settings and update the firmware of the components. I have a bike with a compatible computer, and the lights are always powered (= the switch is on the lamp, not on the computer). But some of the "assist level switches" in this range have it. There's no setting for the light in the app, so it's possible it's a professional-accessible setting in the unit.

The professional one requires a specific device, to connect the bike to the computer. Given this device costs about 250€, not sure you'll find many non-professionals that have it. So the best shot is probably to ask local bike shop that can service Shimano units (not all of workshop do it).

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

I pried the button out with a needle and re-seated it. The button started working again. Now I don't need to go into the settings. Problem solved!